# having a problem in plist file running on iOS : Info.plist: Encountered unexpected element at line 44 (plist can only include one object)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, plist

Below is my Info.plist . When I run putil I get this error
Info.plist: Encountered unexpected element at line 44 (plist can only include one object). I'm not really iOS developer, this is a flutter project I got from another provider

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>home_services</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>smartersvision.com</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `NSAppTransportSecurity` key plus the following dictionary needs to be inside the "root" dictionary:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>home_services</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>smartersvision.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                    <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                    <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```